# What does "Dusted off the old rig" stand for?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

What does "Dusted off the old rig" stand for? Man write this when we say about old mobile.

Comment: "Rig" is a term used for some device.  For a ham radio operator it is the ham radio, but could be used by, eg, a farmer to refer to an old tractor.  To "dust off" a device is to start up (or otherwise begin using) a device that has not been used in some time.

Comment: Well when I first took a look at this I thought it was one of those... "chip off the old block" type of cliche but in reality I'd say that Jesse Steele is probably more right than I so HAHAHAHa you should listen to him
:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Preparing retired equipment for use again

Historically, this depicts an old piece of equipment to being brought out of a shed or other storage, then having the dust removed to make it ready for being put to good use once again.

This can be used as a metaphore or "figurative language" to apply the principle of "readying something" to be useful once again.

[**rig** *n.* 4. (MWD)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rig)

> tackle, equipment, or machinery fitted for a specified purpose

[**dust off** *vt.* (MWD)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dust%20off)

> to bring out or back to use again

---

[Example article *applied to a bicycle*](https://forums.vwvortex.com/showthread.php?4001126-Time-to-dust-off-the-old-rig=)

[Example article *applied to drilling equipment*](https://www.nationaldriller.com/blogs/14-national-driller-blog/post/88825-dust-off-those-classic-drill-rigs)